# Do magic users always have lower attack bonuses than martial characters?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm new to DnD 4e, and my party is creating characters right now. We've noticed that weapon users seem to have attack bonuses in the range of 5-7 (3-4 from ability, and 2-3 from weapon proficiency). Spellcasters, however, seem to have attack bonuses in the range of 3-4, because it doesn't look like they add a proficiency when using an implement.

That's a fairly significant difference in modifier. Is there a bonus to attack for spellcasters that I'm missing? Do spellcasters always have lower attack bonuses than weapon users, or is this mitigated at some point by a mechanic that I can't see?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Implement users have lower attack bonuses by design.

Weapon attacks get a proficiency bonus, while implement attacks do not. This is balanced by the fact that weapon attacks usually (though not always) target AC, while implement attacks always target Fort/Refl/Will (the Non-AC Defenses, or NADs).

A monsters' NADs are *usually* lower than its AC (though brutes often have a Fort that is equal to or even higher than their AC, especially at paragon & epic tiers), and so the disadvantage of not getting a proficiency bonus is generally cancelled out by the advantage of targeting a lower defense value.

Comment: The NADs are not usually lower than AC by enough to compensate for the proficiency bonus, but usually at least ONE is. Most magic users can pick at least one ability for each NAD, letting them target whichever NAD is weakest. It's a little more complex, but usually ends up with more accuracy than a martial, if you pick the right NAD.

Comment: Hehe, attacking the nads.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, per official monster design math of 4e, monster AC defaults to 15+Level, while NADs default to 13+Level. These are of course then modified according to the monster (usually +/- 1-2), but the default comparison is to a +2 proficiency weapon, which comes out even